# Github: use pull request description as merge commit message?

Tags: github

Using Github to manage a repo, by default, the pull request *title* is used as the merge commit message.

I would like to use the pull request *body* as the default merge commit message. Yes, I could copy-paste this into the editor whenever merging a PR, but I'd rather automate this part of the process and not rely on the PR author to remember to copy-paste.

Is there a configuration option to do this somewhere that I'm missing, or a plugin or automated tool that does something like this? Thanks!

A screenshot of creating a Github PR to make it clear:

[image: Github PR creation screen]

(Note that I'm not looking for evangelism about what PRs or commit messages should look like, just technical advice on how to achieve a specific goal.)

Comment: I posted an answer talking about setting up `GIT_EDITOR` but that's for `git` and the question is about github.

Comment: Did you look at https://github.com/community/community/discussions/5955 ? It's obvious that this is a desideratum and there is no provision for it. Anyway, what you're asking is how a web site works, and that's not a programming matter.

Comment: Thank you for the link, matt!
I checked and the top 10 Github-specific questions by score are on root/programming StackOverflow. It seems that the StackOverflow community historically considers questions about commonly used tools like Github to be on topic. Is there an alternative StackExchange community you'd recommend instead?

Comment: You could use the [tag:github-cli] to write a program to build a new commit or commits to use as the PR, but this rapidly gets rather ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [this documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/incorporating-changes-from-a-pull-request/about-pull-request-merges#merge-message-for-a-squash-merge), the default generated commit message depends on the number of commits in the PR - if it's one, that commit message is used. If it's more, the summary will be the PR title, and the description will be a list of the commits in the PR.

The only configuration option I find in the docs relating to this is [here](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/configuring-commit-squashing-for-pull-requests), which allows you to default to using the PR title for all squash merges. Currently I don't believe there is a way to accomplish what you want without just copy-pasting it yourself.

Answer (score 5):

In the repository, go to **Setting -> General** page, I have a section related to PR (see the pic below).

In it, I can choose to include the **PR Title and Description** in the Merge Commit Message.
[image: PR Settings]

NOTE: There is a **lifehack**:

1. PR Description itself [supports templating](https://docs.github.com/en/communities/using-templates-to-encourage-useful-issues-and-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request-template-for-your-repository). Merge Commit Message - not.
2. However, the Merge Commit Message is copied from PR Description.
3. This gives a way to set up an additional template for the Merge Commit Message in the PR Description.

Comment: This was all I needed to get what I needed.